# jfreechart xy series plot data points

Tags: plot, jfreechart

In JFreechart xySeries I want to plot the lines using a very dense set of points in order to show curves with precision, however, I want to plot the points with less density.  For example,  I have 100 data points each one is 1 unit apart on the x axis, but I only want to plot the point every 5 unit.  I do,however, want the lines to be connected every 1 unit in order to show the curve with high density. 
Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can subclass `XYLineAndShapeRenderer` and override `getItemShapeVisible(int series, int item)`.